# Custom dialog doesn't appear to have its set width

Tags: android, xml, dialog, width, customdialog

I have a simple dialog which shows only two options ("Edit" and "Delete"). I set its layout in the .xml file specifying a given width in the attributes. However, in the app it appears as narrow as "wrap_content" was set. It's just wide enough to wrap the text. How could I overcome this issue? Probably I'm missing something really simple. Here's the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/dialog"
android:layout_width="350dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"   >
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/editOption"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
  android:text="@string/edit"
  android:textAlignment="center"
  android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
  android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/deleteOption"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
  android:text="@string/delete"
  android:textAlignment="center"
  android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
  android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's just wide enough to wrap the text. How could I overcome this issue? you want the text to align vertically or horizontally..?

Comment: Vertically, I mean, one below the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change layout width into minimum width:

```
android:layout_width="350dp" <- instead
android:minWidth="350dp" <- insert
```

Comment: Ok, the attribute `minWidth` solves the issue, thank you! 
Anyway, why is it so necessary? If I specific the layout width differently from "wrap_content", why does it just wrap the content? I want to understand this logic.

Comment: It depends on Android version, device, theme.
Android is retarded becacuse of the number of different distributions to support. Something works on Pixel, but it doesn't work on Samsung, Huawei or LG. When it comes to your example, it works without my change on OnePlus 3T.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.